# Не посылается Content-Type header со значением application/json

Tags: javascript

```js
    var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
    
    var header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    header.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    var request = new Request(URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      body: jsonObj,
      headers: header
    });
    
    fetch(request)
     .then( (responce) => {
        if (!responce.ok) {
          return Promise.reject(new Error(
          'Responce failed: ' + responce.status + ' (' + responce.statusText + ')'
      ));
    }
  })
```

В IE header отправляется как нужно. А вот в Chrome и Firefox при отправке запроса header становится таким: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8". Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: не нужно пилить под вредный IE :)

Comment: Если убрать `mode: 'no-cors'`, то заголовки ставятся как положено, но почему так, пока не понял

Comment: Я вот тоже не понимаю, поэтому и спрашиваю :)
Просто у меня сервер и клиент на разных портах localhost. Браузер требует вернуть хидер Access-Control-Allow-Origin с доменом, с которого идет запрос от клиента либо включить мод 'no-cors'. Я подключил этот мод и появилась новая проблема.